# Parallel complex vectors

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that vectors defined by complex numbers $z_1$ and $z_2$ are parallel if and only if $\operatorname{Im}(z_1 \bar{z_2})=0$.

Does the proofing use the fact that in $\mathbb{R}^2$ the cross product of two vectors is scalar as in $\mathbf{u}\times\mathbf{v}=u_1 v_2 -u_2 v_1=0 \to \text{parallel}$.

Also $\operatorname{Im}(z_1 \bar{z_2})=0$ if $z_1=z_2$ so then the expression reduces to $\operatorname{Im}(x^2 +y^2+\underbrace{i(-xy+xy)}_{=0})=0$.

So two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ are parallel if $u_1 v_2 -u_2 v_1 = 0 $ then for the complex numbers it has to be that $u_1=y_1=x$ and $u_2=v_2=y$?

I'm not sure if this is the way to show the proof though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd rather go this way: write $\;z_1=(a,b)\;,\;\;z_2=(x,y)\;,\;\;a,b,x,y\in\Bbb R\;$ .

Then, $\;z_1\,,\;z_2\;$ are parallel iff

$$\exists\;k\in\Bbb R\;\;s.t.\;\;(x,y)=k(a,b)=(ka,kb)\iff$$

$$ z_1\overline z_2=(a,b)(ka,-kb):=\left(k(a^2+b^2)\;,\;k(-ab+ab)\right)=\left(k(a^2+b^2)\;,\;0\right)\iff$$

$$\iff\text{Im}\,(z_1\overline z_2)=0$$

Note: the last backward implication ($\Leftarrow$) is not obvious but can be deduced as follows:

$$\text{Im}\,(z_1\overline z_2)=0 \implies \text{Im}\,((ax+by,bx-ay))=0\implies bx-ay=0\implies \frac{x}{a}=\frac{y}{b}=k$$

Comment: With this $(x,y)=k(a,b)$ you mean $z_1$ and $z_2$ are parallel but with different modulus? Nice way to show the proof. Thanks!

Comment: this seems stupid but what is s.t. short for in "There exists $k$ in $\mathbb{R}$ s.t.

Comment: @ELEC, short writing for "such that" . Many of us, mathematicians, are pretty lazy.